# Change cursor speed in libinput

Tags: libinput

I'm using `libinput` on my Ubuntu 16.04 , I am able to change some of the touchpad settings such as tap to click and natural scrolling, but I'm not sure how to change the cursor speed. I googled it and didn't find much help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the cursor speed in two ways:

1. Set an option in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

On original 16.04, or 16.04.2 stack it is `90-libinput.conf`.

The option is called "AccelSpeed". It is a float number between -1 and 1.

Example:

```
Option "AccelSpeed" "-0.5"
```

will make cursor slower.

2. To test setting before you set it in the conf file you can use `xinput` command. Run it this way:

   ```
   xinput set-prop ID "libinput Accel Speed" -0.5
   ```

The ID is your touchpad ID in `xinput` output.

You can check props by

```
xinput list-props ID
```

The `xinput` setting is not persistent and will be reset after a reboot.

**Note:** The option in `xinput` is with space `Accel Speed` and there is no space in the conf file option `AccelSpeed`.

If you want to see what are other settings, refer to this manual:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man4/libinput.4.html

Comment: It worked, thank you. But I think you meant `90-libinput.conf` not `40-libinput.conf`

Comment: It depends on X.org version. On older version it is 90, on the newer 16.04.3 HWE or 17.04 it is 40.

Comment: I had to prepend `libinput` before the property. So a request that is working for me looks like `xinput set-prop 13 "libinput Accel Speed" 0.7` (as my touchpad has the id `13`.

Comment: Oh, you are correct.

Comment: I find it a bit weird that this is under ``/usr``... I guess there has to be a way to add config files under ``/etc`` which override these?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the response above, I would recommend you configure these via a config file in /etc to avoid having your changes overridden by an Xorg update. One of the paths Xorg is looking for files is `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`. Simply add a new conf file in there. These load alphabetically, so make sure your file is called something like `z-touchpad.conf` to have your changes applied for sure.